# What are things litigators should know about SharePoint for document production purposes?

Tags: search, site-collection, search-scope

I am an attorney who does litigation.  I am also very unfamiliar with the basics of SharePoint -- I only know that it is being used by more and more offices, and soon will be used by mine.  Does anyone have any experience with attempting to collect evidence for litigation (we call it "discovery") from defendants who use SharePoint?  Are there any specific questions or requests I should make when asking for SharePoint files and documents that will make sure I cast a big net and not miss anything important? What terms of art should I know and use to make sure I get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013, there is a feature called eDiscovery that is specifically for auditing and legal purposes. If you had a client that has SharePoint 2013, I would definitely ask for that. The process preserves or captures a snapshot of the site so that no evidence or tampering can take place. It can also span Exchange(email) records as well.

[eDiscovery in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163267.aspx)

In SharePoint 2007-2010, unfortunately there is no eDiscovery, but some important things to recognize is that:

- There can be multiple versions of the same document.
- SharePoint [Site Collection Auditing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA010099726.aspx) can be performed to see what changes were made to a document, or if anything was deleted, permissions changed, etc.
- IIS and ULS Logs are great tools to track down the activity of a user. There are tools to help you read and filter them - [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) being one.

Comment: Can you suggest some terms of art that I should know and understand to make my document request most complete?

Comment: For the eDiscovery, the link Mike provides should have exactly what you need. For the rest of his suggestions I would go with something like "All versions of all documents and list items, and their associated metadata, existing [during the time period in question]", and "All site collection audit logs from the entire SharePoint farm (or from the specific site collections in question, if you need to be exact) created during [time period]", and "All IIS and ULS log files from all servers in the SharePoint farm created during [time period]". Hope that helps, let me know if you need more!